# How can I implement the Comparable interface and write the compareTo method

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to implement Comparable interface and write the compareTo method for my project. I need to write a compareTo metho for the fish with to say an I'a is equal to another I'a the following instance variables should match exactly:

- length
- name

And in order to write a compareTo method, I need to meet the inquiry for compareTo method should compare those instance variables, in that exact order.

The length has highest precedence for ordering, name has next highest precedence.

If the length is the same, then sorting is by the name.
If the name is also the same the compareTo method should return 0 to indicate the two fish are equal.

```
public class I_a implements Comparable<I_a>{
private name;
private length;
}
public abstract class I_a {

   /*** instance constants, these are fixed for each type. ***/
   /** The Hawaiian name. */
   protected final String name;
   /** The English name. */
   protected final String englishName;
   /** The scientific name. */
   protected final String scientificName;
   /** The maximum length. */
   protected final double maxLength;
    /** The minimum length. */
   protected final double minLength;
      /** The diet eaten. */
   protected final String[] diet;
   
   /*** instance variables, these are (possibly) variable for each fish. ***/
    /** The actual fish length in inches. */
   protected double length;
   /** The fish weight in ounces. */
   protected double weight;
   /** The body color. */
   protected String bodyColor;
   /** The fin color. */
   protected String finColor;
   /** The fishes' sex. */
   protected String sex;
   /** The growth rate max per food eaten.*/
   protected double growthRate = 0.8;
```

I try to declare the variable for my Comparable class but it said `<identifier> expected`. What should I try to put

Comment: Why do you have two classes named `I_a`? If they are in the same package, that won't work.

Comment: But what exact problem are you having? Please post your actual code and the full error message.

Comment: I would appreciate confirming my answer if it has resolved your issue and was what you were looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could not describe your problem clearly enough and I couldn't completely understand what you are looking for, But maybe this method is the one you need!!

```
@Override
public int compareTo(I_a i){
    return Comparator.comparing(I_a::getLength)
              .thenComparing(I_a::getName)
              .compare(this, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the options already provided by `Comparator`:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(I_a::getLength).thenComparing(I_a::getName);
```

If you want higher lengths first:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(I_a::getLength).reversed().thenComparing(I_a::getName);
```